# Error when submitting form in Typo3 Code: 201905310232036dfcc153

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I created a Contact Form using the 'Forms' tab and added it as a content element to my Contact page. However, after I submit the form I get the following error message:

Oops, an error occurred! Code: 201905310232036dfcc153

The content of the form is supposed to be send to my e-mail address and the user is supposed to be redirected to the Contact page (so the page is supposed to be refreshed).

Here's a screenshot of the finisher settings for the email to receiver:

[image: Finisher settings of the form for the email receiver]

I am not sure what could be causing the error, so please let me know if there's any code I need to show or screenshots I need to take.

Not sure if it's related but I also keep on getting these errors:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1476107295: PHP Warning: rename(C:/Bitnami/typo3-9.5.6-0/apps/typo3/htdocs/public/typo3temp/var/cache/code/cache_core/5cf29916b377a673163679.temp,C:/Bitnami/typo3-9.5.6-0/apps/typo3/htdocs/public/typo3temp/var/cache/code/cache_core/site-configuration.php): Adgang n�gtet. (code: 5) in C:\Bitnami\typo3-9.5.6-0\apps\typo3\htdocs\public\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Cache\Backend\SimpleFileBackend.php line 234 | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception thrown in file C:\Bitnami\typo3-9.5.6-0\apps\typo3\htdocs\public\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Error\ErrorHandler.php in line 124. Requested URL: http://localhost/typo3/typo3/index.php?route=%%2Fajax%%2Ficons%%2Fcache&token=--AnonymizedToken--
```

Comment: Enable error reporting first of all with `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` so you can better understand what's wrong going on. Also, flush system cache too

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava In which file can I set config.contentObjectExceptionHandler? Flushing the system cache did not solve the problem btw

Comment: You can add this directly in the setup.ts goto from the system template

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava There does not seem to be a setting for contentObjectExceptionHandler in my setup.typoscript. However I did turn on debug mode in my debug settings in configuration presets in the backend